# Pass method as argument

Tags: objective-c, argument-passing

can I pass a method as an argument? 
I don't succeed to pass the method targetOpenView in the example below:

```
-(void) targetTimeView:(id)sender {    
[self TimeViewWithtimeInterval:.6 selector:targetOpenView]; //targetOpenView does NOT work
}

-(void) timeViewWithtimeInterval:(float)interval selector:openViewMethod{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(openViewMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];   
}
```

Any suggestions how I could make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Methods should always start with lower case letters;   i.e. `timeViewWithTimeInterval:selector:`.

Comment: oh ok, I'll take it into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `@selector` compiler directive to extract the select from a method name, like you did when creating the timer:

```
[self TimeViewWithtimeInterval:.6 selector:@selector(targetOpenView)];
```

And define your argument to the type `SEL`:

```
-(void) TimeViewWithtimeInterval:(float)interval selector:(SEL)openViewMethod
{    
 ...
}
```

---

Then, when passing the argument to the NSTimer method you can leave off the `@selector` since the type is already a selector:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self
                               selector:@selector(openViewMethod) /* here */
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];   

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self
                               selector:openViewMethod /* pass it directly */
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I get a message "Use of undefined identifier targetOpenView" at the line [self TimeViewWithtimeInterval:.6 selector:targetOpenView]...

Comment: Update your question w/what you tried.  This answer is correct.

Comment: I added the "(SEL)" in the method "TimeViewWithTimeInterval", but it is the method "targetTimeView" where I have a problem. I immediately get an error when I type "targetOpenView"... he won't let me put a method as an argument...

Comment: No worries :-) I just updated the answer with something I missed.

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry man; the code works, but unfortunately it causes another message to appear when running the code: 2011-10-13 19:35:12.806 Test[37435:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mainViewController openViewMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19d2a0'  Should I make a new post for this question?

Comment: Strange, just to confirm: the section I updated is from inside your second method shown here. You are using it without the `@selector` there, right?

Comment: Crap man Wtf?, I'm gonna buy myself a pair of glasses! And you must be clairvoyant to know this! Thanks again!